# Windows 10 All apps list real sources? Can't remove a folder

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I've installed VS2015 and I cleaned up its start menu items. Moved all to `Visual Studio Tools` folder and deleted `Visual Studio 2015` folder from `All apps`. Recently updated VS2015. It created that folder again. But this time deletion didn't help. I have `Visual Studio 2015` folder in `All apps` list, but actually no such folder in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` nor `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. I moved these links from original folder to `Visual Studio Tools`. Any registry or config sources here? If I choose some link from this unwanted folder and click `Open file location` menu then it leads to `Visual Studio Tools` folder and shows some error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Just moved whole `Visual Studio Tools` folder to any other location, then rebooted, then pasted again in `Start Menu` folder. Rebooted again. Now all shortcuts inside of `Visual Studio Tools` folder and no other VS 2015 folders in `All apps` list.